# Silently checking onion domain is available in bash?

Tags: bash, ping, silent, torsocks

### Context

After having written a working check to see an onion address is reachable:

```bash
onion_address_is_available() {
  local onion_address="$1"

  local ping_output
  ping_output=$(torsocks httping --count 1 "$onion_address")
  if [[ "$ping_output" == *"100,00% failed"* ]]; then
    echo "NOTFOUND"
  elif [[ "$ping_output" == *"1 connects, 1 ok, 0,00% failed, time"* ]]; then
    echo "FOUND"
  else
    echo "Error, did not find status."
    exit 5
  fi
}
```

I would like to make it quiet.

### Output

When I run for example: `torsocks httping --count 1 non_existing.onion`, there are 2 things that show up in the CLI when I run the function:

> 1681750009 ERROR torsocks[134694]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)
> problem connecting to host: Connection refused

and:

> Auto enabling SSL due to https-URL

From what I understand, I can silence commands, both the `stdout` and `stderr` with: `>>/dev/null 2>&1`. However, I would not like to completely silence the command, as I would still like to parse the `*"100,00% failed"*` and `*"1 connects, 1 ok, 0,00% failed, time"*` bits of the output. Hence, I would like to ask:

### Question

How can one silently check in shell-check compliant bash, whether an onion address is available or not?

Comment: Redirect stderr with `2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given by @Barmar in the comments. A working, silent solution was found with: `ping_output=$(torsocks httping --count 1 "$onion_address" 2>/dev/null)`.

The full function is:

```bash
onion_address_is_available() {
  local onion_address="$1"

  local ping_output
  ping_output=$(torsocks httping --count 1 "$onion_address" 2>/dev/null)
  if [[ "$ping_output" == *"100,00% failed"* ]]; then
    echo "NOTFOUND"
  elif [[ "$ping_output" == *"1 connects, 1 ok, 0,00% failed, time"* ]]; then
    echo "FOUND"
  else
    echo "Error, did not find status."
    exit 5
  fi
}
```

and it does not produce any output.